"Error: 'Destination bucket does not exist' when configuring Amazon S3 Inventory for S3 video source bucket"
I'm following an AWS tutorial on batch-transcoding videos https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tutorial-s3-batchops-lambda-mediaconvert-video.html), and I've encountered an issue during step 5 while configuring Amazon S3 Inventory for the S3 video source bucket. After setting up the inventory configuration, I noticed a notification under the "Last export" tab stating "Destination bucket does not exist." I've followed the tutorial step by step, so I'm unsure if I'm doing anything wrong.
I've double-checked the bucket names, ensured they are in the same region. Despite this, the issue persists.

It's probably referring to "The name of the bucket that you created to store the inventory reports (for example, tutorial-bucket-3)."

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
